# How to differentiate between unknown and known absence of information

Tags: sql, database, null

**Context**

- `NULL` is often conflated to mean both unknown data and the known absence of data
- In aggregates (such as `DATE`s or worse, `DATETIME`s), sparse data must be represented with magic values

**Examples**

- The middle name of a person

  - A person who does not have a middle name compared to someone whose middle name is not known
- Someone's birth date and time

  - Differentiating between the time not being known at all vs. the time not being known by your system
  - Knowing someone's month and day of birth but not the year

**Other thoughts, context, and/or approaches**

- If this were a NoSQL context, one could have a "rule" that if a field is known to be absent, it's not stored at all and if it's unknown, stored as a `null`

  - This might make more sense with the rule flipped
  - Aggregates could be broken up and the rule could be applied to individual fields
  - I am admittedly ignorant in the NoSQL realm, but it seems like this would be easy to get wrong
  - For better or for worse, this doesn't apply to a SQL database; omission and `NULL` are the same
- Any field that can be either unknown or absent could have an associated `BOOLEAN` field that states whether it is absent or not

  - This is the only approach that seems bulletproof to me
  - Could seemingly grow to all fields
  - Seems extremely tedious at the very least
- Some "special value" (or values since there are various types) to represent the difference

  - For a text field, perhaps `my-application/unknown` and/or `my-application/absent` (or pick `NULL` for one)
  - Impossible to enforce without ambiguity (if one chose for example `42` for a Unix time, that is also `1970-01-01T00:00:42+00:00`)

**Question**

What are the best practices for dealing with the difference between unknown data and known absence of data?

Comment: "*the difference between unknown data and known absence of data*" - I never had to deal with that. If there is no data, there is no data. I don't really care _why_ it's "unknown". The only situation where this might make a difference are columns that define ranges e.g. start_date/end_date. But there I prefer to use `infinity` rather than `null` to represent an open end

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

The "best practices" depends on the context and the overall data model.  There are lots of different approaches:

- Using a "magic" non-NULL value.
- Using a separate boolean/tinyint column.
- Using an EAV (entity-attribute-value) model.
- Storing the values as JSON or XML (similar to your NOSQL approach).

(and no doubt other methods.)

For your example with the middle name, I find it hard to imagine a scenario where someone is known to have a middle name, but the name (or initial) is not known.  So, `NULL` seems quite appropriate. 
This applies to phone numbers, emails addresses, preferred honorifics and so on.

In practice, I don't find that this is a major concern.  `NULL` seems to work well for most columns.  Admittedly, there are some cases, but those are rather rare.